# Read the start, end points from table and write value into text file based on those points

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I am having below table which has column name & its start & end positions

```
   From    To  Name
    0      25   A
    25     30   B
```

---

```
var fldA = from tbl in tblName.AsEnumerable()
where tbl.Field<string>("Name").Trim().ToUpper() == "A"
select new {
       From = Convert.ToInt32(order.Field<string>(0)),
       To = Convert.ToInt32(order.Field<string>(1)),
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

```
var fldB = from tbl in tblName.AsEnumerable()
    where tbl.Field<string>("Name").Trim().ToUpper() == "B"
    select new {
           From = Convert.ToInt32(order.Field<string>(0)),
           To = Convert.ToInt32(order.Field<string>(1)),
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

```
//fldA contains the value From = 0 & To = 25
//fldB contains the value From = 25 & To = 30
```

Now i am writing text like below

---

```
var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("filepath");
file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-" + (fldA.To - fldA.From).ToString() + "}{1,-"
                        + (fldB.To - fldB.From).ToString()
                        + "}", "HELLO-A", "HELLOOOO-B");
```

Is this a correct approach to write formatted text file.?

Comment: I don't know, why don't you run it and find out if it's writing it in the format you want?

Comment: @tnw : yeah it works fine but, this is just i want to know that how we can write values in txt file on specific position in a better way :).

Comment: Define "better", we have no idea what you have in mind. I don't see how this is answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `string` method `PadRight`. If `fldA.From` is always zero:

```
file.WriteLine("HELLO-A".PadRight(fldA.To) +
               "HELLOOOO-B".PadRight(fldB.To - fldB.From));
```

Otherwise:

```
file.WriteLine(new String(' ', fldA.From) +
               "HELLO-A".PadRight(fldA.To - fldA.From) +
               "HELLOOOO-B".PadRight(fldB.To - fldB.From));
```

Comment: So is this correct to use padding instead of String.format ?

Comment: It seems to be easier, it is probably faster, so why not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this - So I have written query to put in dictionary and then you can get the keys using name or make it generic to dump anything:

```
 EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> rowCollection = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
        //Conert to dictionary
        var result = (from row in rowCollection
            select new
            {
                From = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<string>(0)),
                To = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<string>(1)),
                Name = row.Field<string>(2)
            }).ToDictionary(s => s.Name);

        var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("filepath");
        foreach (var data in result)
        {
            //  data.Key is the name in the table
            file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-" + (data.Value.To - data.Value.From).ToString() + "}"));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
var a = tblName.Where(t=>t.name=="A").Single();
var b = tblName.Where(t=>t.name=="B").Single();
using(var writer = new StringWriter(new StreamWriter("path"))){
    writer.Write(...);
}
```